# Question about Doa Yunus

Tags: surah

Is doa Yunus taken from Surah Yunus? 
And what is the fazilat and uses of Doa Yunus?

Because I read in some places about reading it 40 times or more at dark night in a sizdah, and its beneficial, then I thought that I should read Surah Yunus 40 times, and was thinking it may take a whole day, so how is it possible? Later I found that its not the whole sura but doa Yunus only.

But should I recite it at the darkness of night or same beneficial for day time too?

Jazakallah Khair

Comment: Make sure what ever you recite, the words come from your heart not only from your mouth.

Comment: InShaAllah.. that will definitely come from true belief.. Jazakallah Khair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assalamualaikum,

There is only one hadith i know of, which is related to this dua, which is:

> Sa’d ibn Waqas (radiAllahu anhu) reported that the Prophet (salAllahu
>   allayhi wasalam) said, “The supplication made by the Companion of the
>   Fish (Prophet Yunus (as)) in the belly of the fish was (the above). If
>   any Muslim supplicates in these words, his supplication will be
>   accepted/responded to.” In another report we read, “I know words that
>   will cause Allah to remove one’s distress. These are the words (of
>   supplication) of my brother Yunus, peace be upon him” [at-Tirmidhi;
>   3500, an-Nisa’i in `Amal al-yawmi wa al-layla; #656, al-Hakim 1:505
>   and 2:383. The latter declared it sound (sahih) and Dhahabi confirmed
>   him]

So far, only this hadith proves its importance, and you can clearly see that there is absolutely nothing like when to read it, how many times read it etc. So you can read it any time, or the times, where duas are accepted mote

Please be Very Very careful in people telling you about how to recite, which dua or verse of Quran, how many times, UNLESS there is an authentic reference available for it in Quran and hadith clearly. If you read this dua 40 times daily, in a way that its part of islam,then it is Biddat and evert biddat is going to lead us to hell fire. 
So please be careful. Only stick to, what is in Quran and hadith.

Comment: Walaikumassala brother,

Good information and thanks for making me aware about biddat. I was confused about that too.. 

Jazakallah Khair

Comment: waiyaki sister, please spread the knowldge of islam to other people too,as dawah is an obligation on all muslims

Comment: InShaAllah, I'll try my best. May Allah give us much knowledge to do it in the best way..